# Soundcloud SDK with Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, sdk, soundcloud

I'm currently developing a web app on NodeJS, and chose to use Heroku for the hosting. Now, before I started using Heroku, I would simply test my app in local and everything worked just fine.

When deploying my app, my soundcloud iFrames didn't work anymore. I check the source code with F12 to notice that my app didn't successfully call the Soundcloud SDK. (http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js)

I figured I could host the file in my app, so I did, but it doesn't work because the file's unable to make the calls to other files dependencies. Regardless, when following the documentation; https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks , it recommends simply linking it externally.

Now, my question and problem: Why can't my app successfully call the JS file when deployed, but works perfectly fine in local?

Comment: So I was able to find the source of my own problem. This could be handy for other programmers new to web developing.

When deploying your site, accessing it through https instead of http can prevent you from loading some SDKs. Just use http and everything should work just fine.